# boost serialization warning C4308: negative integral constant converted to unsigned type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, serialization, boost

my struct :

```
  struct member{
        std::string ip_address;
        std::string port;

    protected:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;

        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar & ip_address;
            ar & port;
        }
    };
```

when I use it to save and load it works perfectly, all the data is as I expect it to be,

```
std::vector<member> members;
std::ostringstream ss; 
boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss); 
oa<<members;


std::istringstream ss_(received_data.data()); 
boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ss_); 
ia>>members;
```

but on compiling I get this warning

```
warning C4308: negative integral constant converted to unsigned type
1>        c:\program files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\serialization\static_warning.hpp(92) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::mpl::print<T>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=boost::serialization::BOOST_SERIALIZATION_STATIC_WARNING_LINE<98>
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\archive\detail\check.hpp(98) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::serialization::static_warning_test<B,L>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            B=false,
1>            L=98
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\archive\detail\oserializer.hpp(313) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::check_object_tracking<T>(void)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=std::vector<member>
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\archive\detail\oserializer.hpp(525) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::save_non_pointer_type<Archive>::invoke<T>(Archive &,T &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>            T=std::vector<member>
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\archive\detail\common_oarchive.hpp(69) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::save<Archive,T>(Archive &,T &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>            T=std::vector<member>
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\archive\basic_text_oarchive.hpp(80) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<Archive>::save_override<T>(T &,int)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>            T=std::vector<member>
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\archive\detail\interface_oarchive.hpp(63) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::basic_text_oarchive<Archive>::save_override<T>(T &,int)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>            T=std::vector<member>
1>        ]
1>        c:\users\user\desktop\shve\shve\member_server.h(58) : see reference to function template instantiation 'Archive &boost::archive::detail::interface_oarchive<Archive>::operator <<<std::vector<_Ty>>(T &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>            _Ty=member,
1>            T=std::vector<member>
1>        ]
```

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: why do I get the warning?How to solve it?

Comment: With other compilers one might get other warning generated for the same cause - e.g. with clang it is: `include/boost/mpl/print.hpp:50:23: warning: division by zero is undefined [-Wdivision-by-zero]`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Boost is nervous that you are [archiving non-const class instances](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#objecttracking) which *might* cause a problem with object tracking if different tracked objects use the same address.

To remove the warning you could cast your object to const:

```
oa << const_cast<const std::vector<member>&>(members);
```

Or you can simply use the & operator:

```
oa & members;
```

That was the source of the warning in this particular (and common) case. In general, this type of compiler warning is generated by Boost on purpose with a call to the `BOOST_STATIC_WARNING` macro and so the cause could be anything that Boost wants you to be careful with. This is generally spelled out in a comment accompanying the macro invocation (which you can locate from your compiler error message). For example, the call for this specific warning came from `boost\archive\detail\check.hpp`:

```
// saving an non-const object of a type not marked "track_never)
// may be an indicator of an error usage of the
// serialization library and should be double checked.  
// See documentation on object tracking.  Also, see the 
// "rationale" section of the documenation
// for motivation for this checking.

BOOST_STATIC_WARNING(typex::value);
```

Comment: Hm, what is the reason that boost thinks that the `&` operator is safer to use in that context? An alternative (for some use cases) is perhaps also to use `BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING(, boost::serialization::track_never)` - e.g. when serializing objects from the stack.

Comment: I had tracked down the referenced explanation, but still had no idea what to do - I wish that comment included reference to the `&` operator.